# How to consistently separate elements on a HStack

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a set of elements on a `HStack` that are composed of a circle and some label text underneath it. These elements have a separation between them.

[image: A picture of the elements]

Everything works as expected until one of the labels is bigger than the circle. Then, the text increases the actual width of the element, making the visible separation between the circles, off.

[image]

Is there any way to evenly separate the circles, ignoring the text?

```swift
struct Item: View {
    let color: Color
    let label: String
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Circle()
                .fill(color)
                .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
            Text(label)
        }
    }
}

struct ItemSeparation: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack(alignment: .top, spacing: 30) {
            Item(color: .yellow, label: "Berlin")
            Item(color: .green, label: "Copenhagen")
            Item(color: .blue, label: "Madrid")
            Item(color: .purple, label: "Helsinki")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You could set the width of all the frames, to the width of the max.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two solutions have different compromises. You'll need to decide what happens, for example, if the views will be too wide for the parent view based on the longest label. Option 1 wraps the text. Option 2 makes the view expand beyond its parent.

**Option #1:**

Use `LazyVGrid`:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let columns = [
            GridItem(.flexible()),
            GridItem(.flexible()),
            GridItem(.flexible()),
            GridItem(.flexible()),
        ]

    
    var body: some View {
        LazyVGrid(columns: columns, spacing: 30) {
            Item(color: .yellow, label: "Berlin")
            Item(color: .green, label: "Copenhagen")
            Item(color: .blue, label: "Madrid")
            Item(color: .purple, label: "Helsinki")
        }
    }
}
```

**Option #2:**

Use a `PreferenceKey` and a `GeometryReader` to get the size of the widest `View` and propagate the changes back up to the parent.

```
struct Item: View {
    let color: Color
    let label: String
    let width: CGFloat
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Circle()
                .fill(color)
                .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
            Text(label)
        }
        .border(Color.blue)
        .background(
            GeometryReader {
                Color.clear.preference(key: ViewWidthKey.self,
                                   value: $0.size.width)
            }.scaledToFill()
        )
        .frame(width: width)
    }
}

struct ViewWidthKey: PreferenceKey {
    static var defaultValue: CGFloat { 0 }
    static func reduce(value: inout Value, nextValue: () -> Value) {
        let nextValue = nextValue()
        guard nextValue > value else { return }
        value = nextValue
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var maxWidth : CGFloat = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack(alignment: .top, spacing: 30) {
            Item(color: .yellow, label: "Berlin", width: maxWidth)
            Item(color: .green, label: "Copenhagen", width: maxWidth)
            Item(color: .blue, label: "Madrid", width: maxWidth)
            Item(color: .purple, label: "Helsinki", width: maxWidth)
        }.onPreferenceChange(ViewWidthKey.self) { width in
            self.maxWidth = width
            print(width)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. Option #2 was precisely what I was looking for. Thank you!